# Issues aligning bordered text boxes under images so they move together

Tags: css, image, html, alignment

Currently having issues trying to get these bordered text boxed to stay aligned with the above images in a way that when I re-size the page they stick with their prospective images. Currently I have them forced to stick under the images with margin css but once I re-size the boxes, the boxes all flee under the images.

EDIT: Updated code - still having similar issues but this looks more promising - attaching photo of current state. 
[image: Current issue after updating code]

```
    <body>

        <div id="container">

            <div id="header">
                <img class="leaf" src="images/freshleaf.png" height="150px" alt="freshtext"/>
                <!--<button class="navbutton"> <strong> TEST </strong> </button>-->
            </div>

            <div id="body">
                <div id="main" class="">
                    <div class="column">
                        <img class="smart" src="images/phone1.png" height="500px" alt="phone1"/>
                        <div class="box1"> <h3>Pie is tasty Mmmmm...</h3> </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column">
                        <img class="smart" src="images/phone2.png" height="500px" alt="phone2"/>
                        <div class="box2"> <h3>Pie is tasty Mmmmm...</h3> </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column">
                        <img class="smart" src="images/phone3.png" height="500px" alt="phone3"/>
                        <div class="box3"> <h3>Pie is tasty Mmmmm...</h3> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

#body{
   text-align: center;
}

#header {
   padding-bottom: 50px;
   text-align: center;
}

#main{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:left;
    width: 770px;
}

.column{
   float:left;
   padding-left: 10px;
}

.column:first-child {
   padding-left: 0px;
}

.box1{
   border: dotted;
   border-color: gray;
   padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
   max-width: 250px;
   text-align: center;
}

img.smart{
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap each image and the coresponding text in one container and set `float:left` in the css. get rid of the `#textboxes` div. then center your `#main` div by setting it to the width of all the images (plus padding - if desired). 
see example fiddle with all the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/QLvt7/4/

Comment: I thought that was going to do it, but what I have now is two images on one line and the third underneath. I messed around with the margins/padding and I get the same result or end up with all the images stacking up in a vertical line.

Comment: do the following steps in your CSS: adjust the `#main` width to match your _3 x images + 2 x padding_  **&** get rid of the `img.smart` margin **&** to play it save, set the width of `.column` to the width of your images